# issue when unchecking radio buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

Here is a group of radio buttons:

```
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" name="g" />rbtn 1
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" name="g" />rbtn 2
<input id="Radio3" type="radio" name="g" />rbtn 3
<div id="test">Click this div to uncheck selected radio button</div>
```

And my jQuery code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            //alert("clicked");
            $(":checked").removeAttr("checked");
            //$(":checked").attr("checked", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

For some reason, I can't see any radio button has been unchecked when I click the div. I have also tried to use attr() method to set checked equals false, but still no luck. Could anyone give me a little hint here?

EDIT:

I don't know if it's because using ASP page causes the problem. I doubt so though. Just can't think of anything else that stops it working. So weird.

EDIT2:

I think I have found the actual cause. The problem seems to be the `DOCTYPE`. I wouldn't have thought of that in the first place, really. T_T

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

The above was I originally had with my HTML, and when I took it out, jQuery seemed to be working all right :)

Any explanation on that?

EDIT3:

I think by removing `DOCTYPE` we will be using IE's quirks mode. So for non-IE browsers, it actually won't help.

FINAL EDIT:

**Finally I can stop scratching my head by upgrading jQuery code to the latest version. Indeed, jQuery 1.6.2 is a lot better than jQuery 1.6. :D**

Comment: It seems to be working just fine. [See this fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/e8zkt/).

Comment: Seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/aKKA5/

Comment: Isn't it simply because 1 radio button is always checked? Radio buttons are designed to always have 1 choice checked, so I'd imagine that's what's going on. Is it consistent from browser to browser? (Edit: Well, either it's just your browser, or the bug is somewhere else, since the 2 fiddles above work just fine)

Comment: I am using FF5, and I test the above code on IE8 as well. It's just not working for me. :(

Comment: When you uncomment the alert in the above script. Are you able to see the alert.

Comment: @samir yes, I can see the popup alert. The click event should be problem-free, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any piece of code given here should be fine, as long as the JQuery code is up-to-date. A lesson for me to remember to upgrade JQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

http://jsfiddle.net/RSU46/

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').live('click', function () {
        $('input[name=g]:radio').removeAttr('checked');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#test").click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
        $("input:checked").removeAttr("checked");

    });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2QgxN/

Answer (score 0):

```
try this.
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#test").click(function () {
            //alert("clicked");
            //$(":checked").removeAttr("checked");
              $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");

            //$(":checked").attr("checked", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

you need to specify the type of selector here `$(":checked").attr("checked", false);` or `$(":checked").removeAttr("checked");`in your code does not specify which checked item

Answer (score 0):

well, your code works for me. I tested in FF and IE 7, 8, 9. But you can try  this line as well for unckecking the radio.

```
 $("input[name=g]:checked").attr("checked",false);
```

Else I think you should check if you've js enabled while checking the far unlikly case though.

Answer (score 0):

All the above procedures work for me. And yes, upgrading jquery is a great help. As for `.live()`, it works in jquery version 1.6.2 very well, but as of jquery 1.7.7, the code is deprecated. jQuery suggests using `.on()` instead of `.live()`.

You can refer to this link http://api.jquery.com/live/ for further detail.